# Fixed tabular layout on web page

Tags: html, css, tabular

I would like to present the intermediate steps of a division the pen and paper method on a web page.

The result should like "written" on graph paper / checkered paper.

- I could use a table, but WCAG says that's not the way.
- I could use a fixed width font and `<pre>`, but what if I dislike fixed width fonts?

This image explains it better:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Division_Schriftlich.jpg

Vertical linage is important.

Comment: That looks very promising, I will try to do it like that and mark as solved if it's working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using divs. And size of type of text will work with this. Please note you have to read the columns vertically to add text.

HTML

```
<div class="col">1<br>1<br></div>
<div class="col">3<br>2<br>1<br>1</div>
<div class="col">0<br>0<br>0<br>0</div>
<div class="col">7<br><br>7<br>5<br>2<br>1</div>
<div class="col"><br><br><br><br>0<br>5</div>
<div class="col"><br></div>
```

CSS

```
.col {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Example with borders (to show vertical alignment) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7mzM/)

Example without borders [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7mzM/1/)

A method using non-breakable spaces, for example:

```
1307<br>
120<br>
&nbsp;107<br>
&nbsp;105<br>
```

will not align properly. Therefore discarding horizontal alignment, I think vertical alignment is the best option.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/d7mzM/2/) with the enhanced layout